# Failed tests after installing EcomDev_PHPUnit

Tags: magento, testing, phpunit

For setting up EcomDev_PHPUnit, I installed PHPUnit and relevant modules via PEAR and when I ran "phpunit" for a magento instance, out of 32 tests, 14 were failures and all the failed tests have a similar pattern. Any clues on how to fix this would be helpful.

=== **Example 1**:

```
EcomDev_PHPUnitTest_Test_Lib_Constraint_Config_Resource_Script::testGetVersionScriptsDiff with data set "to_1.0.5_one_invalid" ('directory_one_invalid', 'scheme', NULL, '1.0.5')
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
Array (
'expected' => Array (

0 => 'install-1.0.0.php'
1 => 'upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php'
2 => 'upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.5.php'
0 => 'install-1.0.5.php' ) 'actual' => Array (
0 => 'upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php' ) )
```

=== **Example 2**

```
EcomDev_PHPUnitTest_Test_Lib_Constraint_Config_Resource_Script::testParseVersions with data set "directory_one_invalid" ('directory_one_invalid')
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
Array (
'scheme' => Array (
'install' => Array ()
'upgrade' => Array (

0 => Array (...) ) ) 'data' => Array (...) )
```

**=== Example 3:**

```
EcomDev_PHPUnitTest_Test_Lib_Constraint_Config_Resource_Script::testGetVersionScriptsDiff with data set "from_1.0.0_one" ('directory_one_valid', 'scheme', '1.0.0', NULL)
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
     'expected' => Array (
         0 => 'install-1.0.0.php'
-        1 => 'upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php'
     )
     'actual' => Array (
-        0 => 'install-1.0.0.php'
-        1 => 'upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php'
     )
 )
```